# How to make scp in Shell Script ask me for password

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp, csh

I am making a script to securely transfer data between my two machines through `scp`.

But in the script, it shows an error due to no password. So how can I make my shell script to ask me for password after executing `scp` command?

Here is my `csh` script.

```
# ssh shahk@sj-shahk
# ls -al
echo "Source Location of Remote Server - $1"
echo "Destination Location of Local Server - $2"
echo "File/Folder to be Transferred from Remote Server - $3"

echo "File Transfer Starts"
scp -rv $1/$3 <username>@<hostname>:$2
echo "File Transfer Completed"

# exit
```

Now I am using the above script with `ssh` in following way.

```
ssh <username>@<hostname> "<script name> <args>"
```

When I use in the above manner, it does not prompt for password while executing `scp` command.

Comment: `scp` should ask for a password when it's run from a script, just like it does when run by hand. Are you redirecting input when running the script?

Comment: It does not ask for any password in my case. In fact it just terminates the command.

Comment: Even when you use it interactively? Do you have a private key configured? What does `scp -v` show?

Comment: Nope, if I use `scp` in shell command line, then it asks for password. But if the command is inside a script, then it does not.

Comment: Programs don't run differently inside a script, unless the script does something like redirect the input. Post your script.

Comment: Updated the question with script

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work. How are you running the script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130099/discussion-between-karan-shah-and-barmar).

Answer (score 3):

You can use sshpass
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/

I have used it once to directly scp or ssh without prompting password.

For example :

```
 sshpass -p 'password' scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup
```

Comment: @Aserre Thanks 
sshpass -p 'password' scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answer, `sshpass` will do the job perfectly. In the case where you can not install new packages on your local computer, you can also use `expect` (installed by default on most distros) to automate your interactive session.

The basic syntax of expect is to wait for the program to display a specific string (`expect mystring`), which triggers a specific behaviour (`send command`)

The following script shows the basic structure to implement what you need :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# syntax to specify which command to monitor
spawn scp myfile user@remote.host:/dest_folder

# this syntax means we expect the spawned program to display "password: "
# expect can understand regex and glob as well. read the man page for more details
expect "password: "

# the \r is needed to submit the command
send "PASSWORD\r"

# expect "$ " means we wait for anything to be written.
# change if you want to handle incorrect passwords
expect "$ "
send "other_command_to_execute_on_remote\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

---

As a side note, you can also set up passwordless authorizations through ssh keys.

```
#1) create a new ssh key on your local computer
> ssh-keygen -t rsa
#2) copy your public key to your remote server
# you will need to login, but only once. Once the key is on the remote server, you'll be able to connect without password.
> ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ip_machine
# OR
> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@ip_machine "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

[This tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/) explains how to use the `keychain` tool to manage several ssh keys and users.

Comment: I tries with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, but somehow it didnt work for me

Comment: @KaranShah what did it do ? Did you get an error message ? What is the output of `ls ~/.ssh` ?

Comment: Getting error : debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: @KaranShah Check your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on your remote machine. Make sure it has the following lines : `RSAAuthentication yes` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes`.  Also, make sure you have proper authorizations on your remote `.ssh` folder : `chmod 700 ~/.ssh/*`

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh <username>@<hostname> "<script name> <args>"
```

`scp` will only read a password from a TTY, and it doesn't have a TTY in this case. When you run `ssh` and specify a command to be executed on the remote system (as you're doing here), ssh by default doesn't allocate a PTY (pseudo-tty) on the remote system. Your script and all of the commands launched from it--including `scp`--end up running without a TTY.

You can use the ssh `-t` option to make it allocate a tty on the remote system:

```
ssh -t <username>@<hostname> "<script name> <args>"
```

If you get a message like "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal", then add another `-t`:

```
ssh -tt <username>@<hostname> "<script name> <args>"
```